# remote: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat). Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27

Tags: python, sql, azure

I'm having great difficulties setting up database on my production server in microsoft azure. Everything works perfectly on local(Had issues too when installing locally but figured after using FreeTDS). However when I try an install pyodbc and do git push azure master.
I encounter the following error.(I do not plan on using the examples they showed on official web as they use weird document database). Want to stick with native SQL.

```
remote: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat). Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27
```

Comment: Are you using Azure WebApp? If not, please precise. If yes, please read this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/08/04/upgrading-python-on-azure-app-service/

Comment: Any update about your trying or more details?